Elastic IP Setup in ECS Fargate
I want to add a static IP to my ECS Fargate service. I am currently able to setup the Elastic IP with a Network Load Balancer but I don't want to add any load balancer.

Why the AWS knowledge center suggests using a Network Load Balancer for assigning Elastic IP to Fargate service?
What are the approaches to add a static Elastic IP to my Fargate service, without using a Load Balancer?


This is currently not possible without Network Load Balancer.  See here.

No, it is not currently possible to add a static IP or Elastic IP address directly to a Fargate task. However, you can first create a Fargate Service with a Network Load Balancer, and then attach the Elastic IP address of the task to the Load Balancer.
You can find more details about this process here: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-static-elastic-ip-address

